# I delete from a table where if one column is null i need to use another column

Tags: sql, db2

```
DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE
    CASE 
       WHEN ODUDAT IS NOT NULL
          THEN ODUDAT > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM')   
       ELSE ODCDAT > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM')         
    END
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: Sorry.  I get the following errors.   Formatting error encountered...   Line 5: "END" inserted to complete scope   Line 1: "ERROR_TOKEN" unexpected token(s) ignored   Line 3: "END" inserted to complete scope   Line 6: "AND" expected instead of this input   Line 7: "ERROR_TOKEN" unexpected token(s) ignored   Failed to format 1 statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get the desired results that you are looking for. Create a temporary table to hold the primary keys of the rows you want to delete, then delete them from the table once you gather them all.

```
DECLARE @foundIDs TABLE ( ID INT )

INSERT INTO @foundIDs
SELECT ID FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE ODUDAT IS NULL
AND ODUDAT > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM')

INSERT INTO @foundIDs
SELECT ID FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE ODUDAT IS NOT NULL
AND ODCDAT > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM')

DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @foundIDs)
```

After the comment about not being able to declare temporary tables in DB2, here is an alternative way to do this:

```
DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
    WHERE ODUDAT IS NULL
    AND ODUDAT > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM'))
OR ID IN (SELECT ID FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
    WHERE ODUDAT IS NOT NULL
    AND ODCDAT > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM'))
```

Comment: It is DB2.  Run SQL Scripts.  You can't declare a table in DB2.

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Much more simple solution without correlated sub queries and need for ID:

```
DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE COALESCE (ODUDAT, ODCDAT) > to_char(current_date - 2 month, 'MM');
```

Comment: I did not think of the COALESCE.  UGH.  Can I ask another question?

Comment: I need to add day and year as well as Month.  I added MMDDYYYY  What do i change MONTH to in this scenario?